# How to Sum value according to other column value in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, sum

I'm cakephp learner and working on a project. 
I have a problem. I did google but unable to find the right solution. I hope, I can find the solution here.

Here is My Code.

```
function getCompanySales(){
  $model=ClassRegistry::init('Customer');
  $modelcompany=ClassRegistry::init('Company');
  $from = date("Y-m")."-01 00:00:00";
  $days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m'), date('Y'));
  $to =  date("Y-m")."-".$days_in_month." 24:00:00";
  $companyname=$modelcompany->find('all');
  $companiessales=$model->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => array(
                    "AND" =>array(
                       "Customer.created >=" => $from,
                       "Customer.created <=" => $to
                                  )
                      ),
    'recursive'=>-1
      )
  );
 return $companiessales;
} // Get Company list
```

and I'm getting result like

```
    Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [Customer] => Array ( [gateway] => 10 [amount] => 349 ) ) 
    [1] => Array ( [Customer] => Array ( [gateway] => 7 [amount] => 150 ) ) 
    [2] => Array ( [Customer] => Array ( [gateway] => 13 [amount] => 349 ) ) 
    [3] => Array ( [Customer] => Array ( [gateway] => 10 [amount] => 350 ) ) 
    [4] => Array ( [Customer] => Array ( [gateway] => 7 [amount] => 100 ) ) 
    [5] => Array ( [Customer] => Array ( [gateway] => 9 [amount] => 299 ) ) 
    [6] => Array ( [Customer] => Array ( [gateway] => 7 [amount] => 249 ) ) 
    [7] => Array ( [Customer] => Array ( [gateway] => 10 [amount] => 249 ) ) 
    [8] => Array ( [Customer] => Array ( [gateway] => 7 [amount] => 299 ) ) 
    [9] => Array ( [Customer] => Array ( [gateway] => 12 [amount] => 199 ) ) 
    [10] => Array ( [Customer] => Array ( [gateway] => 7 [amount] => 150 ) )      )
```

But I want to Sum the Value with same gateway like

```
    array(
    [7] => 948 //sum of gateway 7
    [9] => 299 //sum of gateway 9
    [10] => 948 //sum of gateway 10
    [12] => 199 //sum of gateway 12
    [13] => 349 //sum of gateway 13
    )
```

In another query =>

```
    array(
    [7] => company 1
    [9] => company 2 
    [10] => company 3
    [12] => company 4
    [13] => company 5

    )
```

I want a final result as

```
    array(
    [company1] => 948
    [company1] => 299
    [company1] => 948
    [company1] => 199
    [company1] => 349
    )
```

Thanks for all your help. I'm sure I'll get the easy steps to resolve the issue.

Comment: is there any relation between the companies and the customer. If it is there then we can try using a query otherwise, you will have to loop out for companies and the customers. Please share the schema of these 2 tables. Also, share the cakephp version.

Comment: Both table are unique, we have create a link within these two tables. But yes, Companies tables ID is gateway (id) in Customer table.

Comment: cakephp version 2.0

Comment: Please give me any idea, I'm unable to find on google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for stackoverflow to give me ideas and find out an solutions.
I, first find the customer list by sum the amount and group by gateway by bellow code. 
in the view use the custom helper to get the name by id. that's what , I was looking for.

```
    $companiessales=$model->find('all',array(
      'fields'=>array(
      'SUM(amount) AS amount',
      'gateway'
      ),
   'group' => 'Customer.gateway',
   'conditions' => array(
                "AND" =>array(
                    "Customer.created >=" => $from,
                    "Customer.created <=" => $to
                    )
                ),
   'recursive'=>-1
   )
  );
```

Here is the code to get the gateway name by id (which we are making primary id by grouping them)..

```
    function getGatewayName($id){
     $model=ClassRegistry::init('Gateway');
     $companiess=$model->find('first',array(
         'fields'=>array('fullname'),
         'conditions'=>array(
         'Gateway.id' => $id,
         ),   
        'recursive'=>-1
       )
      );
      $name=$companiess['Gateway']['fullname'];
      return $name;
    } // Get Payment Gateway Name
```